# "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint"

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

Using: VS 2013, Entity Framework Code First, ASP.NET Web Project MVC

I have 2 models, in one need 2 FK for the same table:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string  Name { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Id1 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id1")]
    public virtual A A1 { get; set; }

    public int Id2 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id2")]
    public virtual A A2 { get; set; }
}
```

After `enable-migration` and `Add-Migration Test`, when I run `Update-Database`, I get this message:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.B_dbo.A_Id2' on table 'B' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Comment: I think, attributes are redundant, cuz EF treats Id1 and Id2 props as a keys for appropriate entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string  Name { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Id1 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id1")]
    public virtual A A1 { get; set; }

    public int Id2 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id2")]
    public virtual A A2 { get; set; }
}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<B>()
                    .HasRequired(e => e.A1)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(c => c.Id1)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false)

                    .HasRequired(e => e.A2)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(c => c.Id2)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false)
                    ;       
    }
```

alse you could use inverseProperty attribute.

Comment: You are right, but maybe you can explain to the reader what makes the difference. Also, by the fluent mapping you can do without the attributes.

Comment: when two table have many relation , you must use fluent api for set .WillCascadeOnDelete(false) , and by data Annonation you couldn't do this.

Comment: I use your solution, with small changes: call base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder) in OnModelCreating and remove ForeignKey adnotations in B class. What was real strange for me, if I put, into another project,  the same classes, A & B, and the same code in OnModelCreating, Add-Migration added few fields :  A1_Id = c.Int(),A2_Id = c.Int(),A_Id = c.Int(),A_Id1 = c.Int(),.ForeignKey("dbo.A", t => t.A1_Id).ForeignKey("dbo.A", t => t.A2_Id).ForeignKey("dbo.A", t => t.A_Id).ForeignKey("dbo.A", t => t.A_Id1)